# How to run Stacktrace option to get the stack trace

Tags: android, android-studio, stack-trace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Software I need for my works\Installed Software\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Just scroll further up in the Gradle Console to get to the actual problem. The only time when the Gradle stack trace is likely to be useful is if you are doing fairly advanced Gradle work (custom tasks, custom plugins, etc.). In this case, there is a problem with one of your resources (or possibly your manifest), and the explanation of what is wrong appears a few lines up from the lines that you have reported here.

Comment: As I scroll further up !!! I got this -




Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"F:\\For my work\\Android Projects\\Pojects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.0.1\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}

Comment: Set your `compileSdkVersion` to `23`, either by editing your `app/build.gradle` file or through the Project Structure dialog.